# Convert 'tabulated' string of pandas dataframe back into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I will try and illustrate my problem with an example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
example_df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,2],['b',3,4],['c',5,6]], columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Now I convert this dataframe to a tabulated string like so

```
from tabulate import tabulate
example_string = tabulate(example_df, headers=list(example_df.columns), tablefmt='jira', showindex="never")
```

example_string then looks like this...

```
"|| col1   ||   col2 ||   col3 ||\n| a      |      1 |      2 |\n| b      |      3 |      4 |\n| c      |      5 |      6 |"
```

So my question is - how can I convert this string back into a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` can parse a string if you use `StringIO` with `pd.read_csv`.

The biggest issue here is that the column labels have a different separator (`'||'`) than the data (`'|'`), and there is also an additional `'|'` around the table. To deal with this, we will read in the header and data separately then combine them into a single DataFrame. The `.dropna` removes the additional columns on the edges created by the table border `'|'`

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

header = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(example_string), sep=r'\|\|', engine='python', 
                      nrows=1, header=None)
             .dropna(how='all', axis=1))
data = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(example_string), sep=r'\|', engine='python', 
                    skiprows=1, header=None)
          .dropna(how='all', axis=1))

# Replace data's RangeIndex with column labels. 
data.columns = data.columns.map(header.T[0].str.strip().to_dict())
```

---

```
print(data)

       col1  col2  col3
0   a           1     2
1   b           3     4
2   c           5     6
```

One issue with the above is that `object` columns still have all of the extra whitespace. You'll need to strip `'col1'` for instance. Numeric columns were properly typecast. It's a simple fix:

```
for col in data.select_dtypes('O'):
    data[col] = data[col].str.strip()

print(data)

  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     2
1    b     3     4
2    c     5     6
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to apply this example to my work. Using StringIO with read_csv was the real key here!